# Weird behavior when playing audio from Data with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm trying to reproduce an audio that's being sent from my server in a **[UInt8]** buffer. And I've only managed to reproduce it correctly in the following way:

```
let datax = Data(bytes: data, count: data.count)
do
{

    let pl:AVAudioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: datax, fileTypeHint: "m4a")
    pl.volume = 1
    pl.play()

    //Here is the weird part, which I randomly added to make it work. Keep reading to understand.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 100) {
        if(false){
            pl.play()
        }
    }

} catch {
    print("ERROR")
}
```

**What is weird here?**

Pay attention to this part of the code, which it never executes because of the **`if(false){ pl.play() }`**

If I comment this part of the code, the audio doesn't reproduce. Weird huh?

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 100) {
    if(false){
        pl.play()
    }
}
```

If I change the **`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 100)`** to **`DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1)`** (Changing the 100 to 1): The audio only reproduces for 1 second, and it stops playing.

If I comment **`if(false){ pl.play() }`**: The audio never reproduces

**Weird!**

I found this by error, I don't know if it's a bug or what's going on. For now I'm leaving that weird part of code at **100 seconds**, only because I know my audios won't be larger than **100 seconds**.

**What could be happening?**

This is weird, I don't want to put lame code. Is it a bug of the compiler? Do you recommend another way of doing this? Do you have any idea what could be causing this weird behavior?